# Using compareRaster (rasters): different extent?

Tags: raster, r

In R I'm trying to make a RasterStack of RasterLayers, they all have the same format, the only difference is that one of them is a solo raster and the others are bioclimatic variables.
The soil layer had a resolution of ~ 1km and was redesigned to 5km to align with the others.

Comment: Which Software?

Comment: Please read our FAQ on how to ask a good question. We have no idea on the software that you are using, data format or specific information on your rasters (rows, columns, bounding extents). So, any answer is, at best, a guess. Please edit your questions to add some specifics as well as a tag that specifies what software environment you are working in.

Comment: @Jackson, you are making some huge assumptions that this is an R specific question. The term and concept "raster stack" applies to numerous software including the "big box" brands such as ERDAS, ESRI, ENVI, and alignment problems would be just as relevant. Admittedly, this is likely R related but, editing a post without knowing that this was the case is jumping-the-gun a bit and should be avoided. There is nothing in the original post that indicates R!

Comment: @Jeffrey noted. I made the edit as compareRaster is a common/standard function in R (and noted in the title of the post), I agree that I made an assumption (though I would not call it ‘huge’).

Comment: @Jackson, I would note that there are "compareRaster" functions in ENVI-IDL and ERDAS-EML. Yes, exactly the same function call name.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you need them to be the same CRS and resolution in order to stack them. For this. Assuming your 5k raster also has a bigger extent for the purposes of this example, you can use `raster::projectRaster()`:

```
bigger_raster <- projectRaster(raster5k, smaller_raster)
```

Now, if your extents are still off - you'll need to use `raster::crop()` to fix this.

```
new_raster <- crop(bigger_raster,smaller_raster)
```

Now `bigger_raster` will line up with `smaller_raster`.